# Got error when checking req.params.id in express.js route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I am new to full-stack programming. I run into this issue, where I would like to GET data from a JSON file via a GET Method on my local Node.js Express server. I have searched the internet for hours now and read many acticles, but could not figure out what goes wrong.

The idea is that in the JSON file  list of products are hold and these will be loaded to the front end.

There is the main page, which works fine and there is a product page where I am unable to load product details. Each product has an ID, and when I click on the main page on a product only this product should be loaded in the product page.

I have checked the proxies, all function well. When I check the console is see the following: **Failed to load:3000/api/products/[object%20Object]:1
resource: responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

I have the following code:

// server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import data from './data.js';

const app = express();

app.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res) => {
  const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === Number(req.params.id));
  if (product) {
    res.send(product);
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product Not Found' });
  }
});

app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
  res.send(data.products);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Server is ready');
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

// data.js (JSON file)

```
const data = {
    products:[
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: 'Stool',
            category: 'furniture',
            image: '/assets/images/p1.jpg',
            price: 120,
            countInStock: 9,
            brand: 'SKANANA',
            rating: 4.0,
            numReviews: 10,
            description: 'High Quality Product'
        }, {}, {} ],
} 

export default data;
```

// ProductScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { detailsProduct } from '../actions/productActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import Rating from '../components/Rating';

export default function ProductScreen(props){
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productId = useParams();
    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(detailsProduct(productId))
    }, [dispatch, productId]);

    return (
        <div>
        { loading ? (<LoadingBox></LoadingBox>) 
        : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
        ) : (
            <div>
            <Link to="/">Back to Result</Link>
            <div className="row top">
                <div className="col-2">
                    <img clasName="large" src={product.image} alt={product.name}></img>
                </div>
                <div className="col-1">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h1>{product.name}</h1>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Rating rating={product.rating} numReviews={product.numReviews}></Rating>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Price : ${product.price}
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Description:
                            <p>{product.description}</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="col-1">
                    <div className="card card-body">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div>Price</div>
                                    <div className="price">${product.price}</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div>Status</div>
                                    <div>{product.countInStock>0 ? (<span className="success">In Stock</span>):
                                    (<span className="danger">Out of Stock</span>)
                                    }</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button className="primary block">Add to Cart</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )} 
     </div>
       
    )
}
```

Help would be hugely appreciated, let me know if you need more explanation or code :)

-- edit: added React front-end code.

Comment: The problem is in the request, you are not passing the `:id` parameter correctly

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling the api from your front end? looks like the `id` parameter isn't being set right

Comment: Sure, here is a part of my front end code): `export default function ProductScreen(props){
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productId = useParams();
    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(detailsProduct(productId))
    }, [dispatch, productId]);

    return (product...)} `

Comment: I have added the full front-end code above.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the whole object instead of the simple integer id when you are calling the api.

Comment: How can I access the parameter in the right way? I found this article that clearly explains how to, but something is off with my code and I am unable to find out why: https://simonjcarr.medium.com/find-and-filter-arrays-in-javascript-and-node-js-9c4abac65c52

Comment: I asked a programmer to help me out, after 45 minutes we figured it out. For some reason the Router does not send the link correctly. The solution was break up the URL like this (in the Redux part): `const productId = document.location.pathname.split("/")[document.location.pathname.split("/").length - 1]; `